# Sending data with nested JSON

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have a two textfields; (body and user), which i want to parse their data to my json(nested). but the exception is being thrown instead

The snippet below is my JSON representation

```
{
        "id": 27,
        "user": {
            "username": "admin"
        },
        "body": "Saturday morning",
        "updated": "2022-07-30T06:48:53.009515Z",
        "created": "2022-07-30T06:48:53.009515Z"
    },
```

below is how i am sending the data

```
Future<Note> createNote(String body, String username) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    noteUrl,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      'body': body,
      'user': username,
    }),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return Note.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    
    throw Exception('Failed to create note');
    
  }
}
```

this is where i am calling the function to send the data

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  createNote(_bodyController.text, _userController.text);
         Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/');
                },
                child: Text('submit'),
              )
```

Below snippet is my model class(flutter)

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Note> noteFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Note>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Note.fromJson(x)));

String noteToJson(List<Note> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Note {
  Note({
    this.id,
    required this.body,
    this.updated,
    this.created,
    this.user,
  });

  int? id;
  String body;
  DateTime? updated;
  DateTime? created;
  User? user;

  factory Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Note(
        id: json["id"],
        body: json["body"] as String,
        updated: DateTime.parse(json["updated"]),
        created: DateTime.parse(json["created"]),
        user: User.fromJson(json["user"]),
        
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "body": body,
        "updated": updated?.toIso8601String(),
        "created": created?.toIso8601String(),
        "user": user?.toJson()
      };
}


List<User> userFromJson(String str) =>
    List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<User> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));


class User {
  User({
    this.id,
    required this.username,
    this.password,
    this.email,
  });

  String? id;
  String username;
  String? password;
  String? email;


  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
        email: json["email"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "email": email,
      };
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Failed to created note

Comment: response.statusCode?

Comment: Yes, response.statusCode